# How to detect if "Debug Programs" Windows privilege is set?

Tags: winapi

When installing SQL Server 2008, if this privilege is not enabled for the user doing the install, the install fails un-gracefully. So in my app, before installing SQL Server (using its silent install), I'd like to detect whether or not the current running user has the "Debug Programs" privilege set (i.e., SeDebugPrivilege, SE_DEBUG_NAME...)

I don't want to know if the current process has it set (because, apparently, most times it does not, even if the privilege is enabled on the system).  I originally thought that the "PrivilegeCheck" API would work, but it does not.  If you run this code under the VS debugger, then it tells you the privilege is enabled.  If you run it from a command line, it tells you the privilege is disabled.  How should I correct this program to actually be able to check whether or not the privilege is available?

`HANDLE hToken;`

```
// Get the calling thread's access token.
if (!OpenThreadToken(GetCurrentThread(), TOKEN_QUERY, TRUE, &hToken)) 
{
    if (GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_TOKEN)
    {
        printf("CAN'T GET THREAD TOKEN!!!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Retry against process token if no thread token exists.
    if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken))
    {
        printf("CAN'T GET PROCESS TOKEN!!!\n");
        return -1;
    }
}

//Find the LUID for the debug privilege token
LUID luidDebugPrivilege;
if ( !LookupPrivilegeValue( 
    NULL,            // lookup privilege on local system
    "SeDebugPrivilege",   // privilege to lookup 
    &luidDebugPrivilege ) )        // receives LUID of privilege
{
    printf("LookupPrivilegeValue error: %u\n", GetLastError() ); 
    return -1; 
}

PRIVILEGE_SET privs; 
privs.PrivilegeCount = 1;
privs.Control = PRIVILEGE_SET_ALL_NECESSARY;

privs.Privilege[0].Luid = luidDebugPrivilege;
privs.Privilege[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED; 

BOOL bResult;
::PrivilegeCheck(hToken, &privs, &bResult);

if(bResult)
{
    printf("DEBUG ENABLED!\n");
}
else
{
    printf("DEBUG NOT ENABLED!\n");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

OK, we figured this out after posting the original question.  What we actually need to do is attempt to set the "debug programs" privilege for the current process.  If we can enable that privilege, then that means the current logged-in user has that privilege enabled for them in the local security policy editor (gpedit.msc on XP...)

See below for example code, in case anyone else needs to solve this problem!  The important pieces are:

- Use LookupPrivilegeValue() to find the LUID for SeDebugPrivilege. (All the APIs for this stuff need LUIDs...)
- Use GetTokenInformation() to find out what privileges are enabled on this process already.  If the process has the privilege enabled already, that means that the process is most likely being run under a debugger, and that the current logged-in user does have the privilege enabled.
- If the process doesn't have the privilege set, use the AdjustTokenPrivileges() to attempt to set the privilege.  This is in our method AttemptToAddDebugPrivilegeToProcess() below; we return true if the privilege can be set (meaning the current logged-in user has the "debug programs" privilege enabled) or false if it can't.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <strsafe.h>

void ShowLastError(LPTSTR lpszFunction) { 
    // Retrieve the system error message for the last-error code

    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError(); 

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL );

    // Display the error message and exit the process

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, 
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf) + lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction) + 40) * sizeof(TCHAR)); 
    StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, 
        LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
        TEXT("%s failed with error %d: %s"), 
        lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf); 
    printf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf);

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
}



bool LuidsMatch(LUID l1, LUID l2)
{
    return l1.LowPart == l2.LowPart && l1.HighPart == l2.HighPart; }

bool AttemptToAddDebugPrivilegeToProcess(HANDLE hToken) {
    //Find the LUID for the debug privilege token
    LUID luidDebugPrivilege;
    if ( !LookupPrivilegeValue( 
        NULL,            // lookup privilege on local system
        "SeDebugPrivilege",   // privilege to lookup 
        &luidDebugPrivilege ) )        // receives LUID of privilege
    {
        printf("LookupPrivilegeValue error: %u\n", GetLastError() ); 
        return false; 
    }

    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES newState;
    newState.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    newState.Privileges[0].Luid = luidDebugPrivilege;
    newState.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

    if(AdjustTokenPrivileges(
        hToken,
        FALSE,
        &newState,
        sizeof(newState),
        NULL, //&previousState, 
        0))
    {
        if(GetLastError() == ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED)
        {
            printf("Couldn't set debug!!!");
            return false;
        }

        //*************************************************************
        //IF YOU MADE IT HERE, THE USER HAS THE DEBUG PROGRAMS PRIVILEGE
        //*************************************************************
        printf("DEBUG OK!!!");
        return true;
    }

    printf("AdjustTokenPrivileges returned false!!!");
    ShowLastError("AdjustTokenPrivileges");
    return false;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HANDLE hToken;

    // Get the calling thread's access token.
    if (!OpenThreadToken(GetCurrentThread(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES|TOKEN_QUERY, TRUE, &hToken)) 
    {
        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_TOKEN)
        {
            printf("CAN'T GET THREAD TOKEN!!!\n");
            return -1;
        }

        // Retry against process token if no thread token exists.
        if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES|TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken))
        {
            printf("CAN'T GET PROCESS TOKEN!!!\n");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    //Find the LUID for the debug privilege token
    LUID luidDebugPrivilege;
    if ( !LookupPrivilegeValue( 
        NULL,            // lookup privilege on local system
        "SeDebugPrivilege",   // privilege to lookup 
        &luidDebugPrivilege ) )        // receives LUID of privilege
    {
        printf("LookupPrivilegeValue error: %u\n", GetLastError() ); 
        return -1; 
    }


    //Find if the "debug programs" privilege is already assigned to this process
    DWORD dwReturnedDataSize;
    GetTokenInformation(
        hToken,
        TokenPrivileges,
        NULL,
        0,
        &dwReturnedDataSize);

    BYTE* pData = new BYTE[dwReturnedDataSize];
    GetTokenInformation(
        hToken,
        TokenPrivileges,
        pData,
        dwReturnedDataSize,
        &dwReturnedDataSize);

    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES* pPrivileges = (TOKEN_PRIVILEGES*)pData;

    bool bFound = false;

    for(unsigned int count = 0; count PrivilegeCount; count++)
    {
        LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES& luidAndAttrs = pPrivileges->Privileges[count];

        if(LuidsMatch(luidAndAttrs.Luid, luidDebugPrivilege))
        {
            bFound = true;
            if((luidAndAttrs.Attributes & SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED) == SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED)
            {
                //**************************************************************
                //IF YOU MADE IT HERE, THE USER HAS THE DEBUG PROGRAMS PRIVILEGE
                //**************************************************************
            }
            else
            {
                printf("THIS PROCESS DOES NOT HAVE THE DEBUG PROGRAMS PRIVILEGE ENABLED\n");                                AttemptToAddDebugPrivilegeToProcess(hToken);
            }
        }
    }

    if(!bFound)
    {
        printf("THIS PROCESS DOES NOT HAVE THE DEBUG PROGRAMS PRIVILEGE ENABLED\n");
        AttemptToAddDebugPrivilegeToProcess(hToken);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `GetTokenInformation` can be used to retrieve the list of privileges for the process.  `PrivilegeCheck` checks if a privilege is enabled or disabled, and privileges not held by the user will always be disabled.  Privileges held by the user may or may not be disabled (some are disabled by default)

From your question, I think what you really want is to check is if the user is an administrator.

Comment: The administrator user may or may not have that privilege set.  We've run into several instances where our customer has put very "tight" controls on their systems, and even admin does not have the "debug programs" privilege enabled.  I actually ended up finding a solution -- we attempt to set the privilege on the process, and if we CAN set it, then that means the user has the privilege.  If we can't set it, then they do not have the privilege.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correct you can use [LsaEnumerateAccountRights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms721790%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get the list of privileges which the user has.

Comment: There is a thing called a restricted token, so a process running as user X can actually have less privileges than what the user normally has (The big example is UAC with its split token model, but the Safer API added to XP does this as well and IIRC the actual token restriction api was added to 2000)