# Retrieve if my own process have SeDebugPrivilege enabled

Tags: delphi

How can I determine if my own process have SeDebugPrivilege enabled?

Comment: Hi - In my response, I assumed luid returned some kind of bitmask.  I was mistaken.  The answer to your question is here: [How to detect if “Debug Programs” Windows privilege is set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880197/): " What we actually need to do is attempt to set the "debug programs" privilege for the current process. If we can enable that privilege, then that means the current logged-in user has that privilege enabled for them in the local security policy editor"

Comment: I modified the topic with the answer.

Comment: Better post the answer as an answer, then you can accept it.

Comment: Done, but i can't accept. Only can in 2 days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution if somebody more need it.

```
type
  TPrivilegesArray = array [0..1024] of TLuidAndAttributes;
  PPrivilegesArray = ^TPrivilegesArray;
var
  luid          : TLargeInteger;
  LuidSDP       : TLargeInteger;
  hToken        : THandle;

  Size          : Cardinal;
  Privileges    : PTokenPrivileges;
  I             : Integer;

  Name          : string;
  Attr          : Longword;

  function AttrToString: string;
  begin
    Result := 'Disabled';
    if (Attr and SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED) <> 0 then Result := 'Enabled';
    if (Attr and SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED_BY_DEFAULT) <> 0 then Result := 'Enabled By Default';

    Result := Result;
  end;
begin
  OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY, hToken);

  GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenPrivileges, nil, 0, Size);
  Privileges := AllocMem(Size);
  GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenPrivileges, Privileges, Size, Size);
  LookupPrivilegeValue(nil, 'SeDebugPrivilege', LuidSDP);

  for I := 0 to Privileges.PrivilegeCount - 1 do
  begin
    if LuidSDP <> PPrivilegesArray(@Privileges^.Privileges)^[I].Luid then Continue;

    Luid := PPrivilegesArray(@Privileges^.Privileges)^[I].Luid;
    Attr := PPrivilegesArray(@Privileges^.Privileges)^[I].Attributes;
    Size := 0;

    LookupPrivilegeName(nil, Luid, nil, Size);
    SetLength(Name, Size);
    LookupPrivilegeName(nil, Luid, PChar(Name), Size);

    Form1.Memo2.Lines.Add(Format('[%d][%s][%s]', [Luid, PChar(Name), AttrToString]));
  end;

  FreeMem(Privileges);
  CloseHandle(hToken);
```

This code list all privileges and if are disabled, enabled by default or enabled.
After some search and modifications this code are working perfectly.

if need list all privileges just comment the line

```
if LuidSDP <> PPrivilegesArray(@Privileges^.Privileges)^[I].Luid then Continue;
```